# How to use the same object throughout the class once created in C#

Tags: c#, oop, object, methods

This might be really easy but, I am trying to use the same object (with its properties and all instantiated) created in a method in other methods of the class. Tried to look everywhere, even in Singleton patterns but don't know if that is the correct way. I am also new to using advanced features and don't know much. Please ask questions if needed.

For example here is some pseudo code, I instantiate an object called person1 using a class Person with some properties, say

```
name = "John", 
age = 12,
city = "SomeCity"
```

inside a method.

I want to use the same person1 object inside another method to do some work with the properties like to check whether the person is adult or not.

**EDIT**: I have an idea for the answer now thanks to everyone on the comments esp @Corak. This was my first question on Stack. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Please post _some_ code to enhance your question

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: The key to a singleton is that it is the only value ever created. You can do that several ways, most if not all of which use the static keyword in some form, and an `if(singleton == null) singleton = new Singleton();` statement to ensure its created only when it's null before it is returned to the caller.

Comment: I added some more info to the question, will singleton be the correct way?

Comment: You are missing "Public" on the objects so they are not visible outside the class.

Comment: I need the same object to be used inside the class, so I don't think it should be public at all

Comment: You could store the created instance in a property (or member variable or "field") of the class. Or you could let the "creating" method return the instance and then inject the instance as a parameter to the other method. But it's hard to tell, if that's what you mean without seeing some more of the actual code you're using. - A singleton is (only) useful if you have only ever _one_ single instance of a class over all theads over the whole lifetime of the application.

Comment: You probably want to store a private field in your class. It can be created in one method, and you can use that value in other methods. Is this your question ?

Comment: @driis I had done that before. But as I run the method again and again with some new properties of the same object, it would increase the process memory. So I thought this was the wrong way to use the object.

Comment: Show some relevant code and explain what exactly you want to do. Either return it from your method and pass the reference around, or store it in a field.

Comment: @User09061968 - do not stress yourself over premature optimization. First make it work, then make it fast, then make it efficient. Regarding memory usage, you might want to read up on garbage collection. The tl;dr of it is: don't worry about it until it becomes a problem. And also: garbage collecion happens at "random" times, so memory is not freed immediately.

Comment: @Corak Okay, I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might achieve this by storing the instance of `Person` in a private property on your class. For example:

```
public class PersonWrapper
{
    private Person person;

    // ctor
    public PersonWrapper()
    {
       this.person = new Person(){ Age = 12 };       
    }

    public bool IsAdult()
    { 
        return this.person.Age > 18;
    }
}
```